# What is the use of class declaration in c++

Tags: c++

I was going through a c++ code and saw a header file with below declaration:

```
file a.h
class xyz;
```

But that class was not defined any where in the file. I also wrote a code and it perfectly compiles fine. Just wanted to know what is the use of declaring a class like this as it does't enforces programmer to define.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Thanks Ninja for pointing out. I didn't knew the term Forward declaration.

Answer (score 0):

this is a forward declaration of a class.
you can use `xyz*` variables in the header file - the linker will resolve the actual class implementation later

Answer (score 0):

That's a forward declaration (or simply declaration) and it allows you to use the name `xyz` in contexts where a full definition isn't required.

One example is when you have another class which contains a pointer to a `xyz`:

```
class xyz;
class Aux
{
  xyz* k;
};
```

Other uses are return types, parameter types and references.